# Auto Login using Windows authentication Active Directory on another server on domain ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, autologin

I wrote an ASP.NET MVC application and use auto-login using Active Directory users when I add application on IIS on domain controller server it works and logs in automatically. But in the same domain and same network, when I add the application to another server and try to login, it asks for username and password and doesn't automatically log in as when I add it before on the domain controller

Answer (score 1):

Please check iis authentication feature is set as below:

-Enable Windows authentication and disable Anonymous authentication

[image]

you also need to configure IE to enable auto-login:

1)Open Internet explorer

2)Go to tools -> internet options

3)Select security tab-> local internet -> custom level

[image]

4)Under the user authentication select the automatic login with the current username and password radio button.

[image]

Repeat the same steps for the intranet Zone.